# Is the skeleton in the grave in “The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly” that of a recently deceased actress?

Tags: movies

In one of the final scenes of the movie “The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly,” the titular characters dig up a grave in a cemetery to reveal a skeleton.

Several sites online report that this is a real skeleton belonging to a Spanish actress who wanted to keep acting after her death. To the best of my knowledge, these sites don’t cite any sources:

- https://meglioungiornodaleone.wordpress.com/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/55v0lq/til_the_skeleton_found_by_tuco_in_the_good_the/
- https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1kVxxWehLPQ

This claim seems improbable. Is it true?

Comment: I haven't found an answer, but [another random page on the internet](https://westernsallitaliana.blogspot.com/2016/01/spaghetti-western-trivia-arch-stantons.html) provides more details, and also has a comment that may indicate there could be a verifiable source in an Italian documentary about the director, _Verdone racconta Leone_

Comment: @JeffLambert Just saw the documentary [on youtube](https://youtu.be/DQJfWIVeslU), the factoid is reported at 18:40 minutes. It's reported as «a man from the production crew pointed out "I know a man who's mother worked as an actress who wrote a thing in her testament: that she wanted to act even after death". No names, no other references. (I'm italian.) The documentary host knew and worked with Leone, but it doesn't sound like he was present on that set.

Comment: @ZJR If you're able to transcribe the original Italian of the segment and provide your own English translation, combine it with the information from the previous links, it may be the best we can do for this question, barring someone from the original cast/crew having done an interview, or testimony from the actress' family. All of this second-hand information though may just be exactly how the rumor got started, so we're really no closer to an answer.